# While Rendering Canvas control in Png I lost the background image

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

My application is a windows 8 store app . It takes a photo with the camera, then  i draw over the image, and i want to save both the image and the drawing. What i have come result is only the drawing. i lost the background image. 
Below you have my implementation :

**XAML code:** 
(in place of having an Image control for the photo taken and a canvas for the drawing, i binded the photo = CurrentPicture as the background of the canvas)

```
 <Canvas Grid.Row="1"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    x:Name="InkCanvas"
                    Background="{Binding CurrentPicture, Converter={StaticResource WPhotoToCanvasBackgroundConverter}}"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    Margin="0"
                    Width="1024"
                    Height="768" />
```

**C#** :

```
        private async Task<IPhoto> RenderCanvasToPNG()
    {
        MemoryStream stream = await WriteableBitmapRenderExtensions.RenderToPngStream(InkCanvas);
        var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
        await bitmap.SetSourceAsync(System.IO.WindowsRuntimeStreamExtensions.AsRandomAccessStream(stream));
        byte[] byteme = stream.ToArray();
        var photo = new WPhotos(null, byteme, bitmap.PixelWidth, bitmap.PixelHeight, bitmap);
        return photo;
    }
```

Thank you a lot for your time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a direct way to extract the pixels from a BitmapImage or ImageBrush. I believe WriteableBitmapEx fakes this by finding the image's source URI and looking that up, but this method works only if the image was loaded from a URI. If it was streamed into the image then there is no way to extract it.

Instead, you can use [RenderTargetBitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.aspx) to render your UIElements to a bitmap. Since this uses the Xaml rendering engine it has access to the ImageBrush used for the Canvas' background and should completely render the Canvas and its contents (barring non-renderable contents such as a MediaElement or SwapChainPanel).